# Скобки, запятые или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, тире, скобки

Не знаю, правильно ли написано следующее предложение:

> От матери — крайне привлекательной, эффектной женщины — он унаследовал
> не только симпатичную внешность, но и доброту, от отца — это был
> человек статный и волевой — приятный низкий голос и твердость
> характера.

Пояснения, касающиеся родителей, в данном случае чем нужно выделить: скобками, запятыми или тире? Запятыми — вроде бы нет, с тире меня мучают сомнения, а скобки ставить не хочется без уверенности в том, что я не ошибусь. Такая вот дилемма.

Comment: Любой вариант годится. Выбор на усмотрение автора

Answer (score 3):

**В качестве варианта** (уменьшено количество тире):

От матери, крайне привлекательной и эффектной женщины, он унаследовал не только симпатичную внешность, но и доброту, от отца ― это был человек статный и волевой ― приятный низкий голос и твердость характера.

Comment: Это плохо с точки зрения структуры, параллелизм конструкции нарушен. Я бы вообще написал так: *От матери — женщины привлекательной, эффектной — он унаследовал симпатичную внешность и доброту; от отца — мужчины статного, волевого — приятный низкий голос и твердость характера*.

Comment: Это тоже плохо с точки зрения структуры – ваши четыре тире мельтешат перед глазами. Надо искать точку с запятой, чтобы они построились парами. Это сколько же времени нужно! Современный читатель не может себе такого позволить. Так что идеал пока не найден.

Comment: Может позволить. Вы же читали Славникову: у неё и не такие конструкции регулярно встречаются. Злоупотреблять, понятно, не надо, но даже в жёсткой фантастике такие структуры допустимы. Как приём.

Comment: Все жанры хороши, кроме скучного. Если Славникова может себе позволить какие-то сложные конструкции, требующие внимания, то, значит, она чем-то другим привлекает читателя. Может, надо много не рассуждая погрузиться в ее сложный текст, воспринять его на уровне подсознания. Тогда читатель поймет ее художественное пространство. Здесь же я этого не вижу, и мне эти параллели мешают, кажутся искусственно навязанными. Однообразие вообще утомляет: мы даже противопоставление всегда стараемся выразить по-разному, меняя и лексику и синтаксис.

Comment: Да? То есть мой стих "Он любит зиму...", который весь на параллелях, иногда буквальных, существительное к существительному, -- утомителен? :)

Comment: Он – прекрасен! В него влюбляешься  сразу, и даже думать не хочется почему.  Там только чувства, в чистом виде... Ну,  как в вашем фантастическом рассказе, который, может быть, и не фантастический вовсе.   Наверное, вы поймете, о чем я говорю...

Comment: Ничего там не только чувства :) Всё рационализировано и выстроено. И именно поэтому -- потому, что есть скелет -- он и ощущается плюс-минус хорошо. Поверьте, одни чувства без русла -- это невнятный поток сознания, чаще всего бессмысленный. (Есть и такие книги, и такой жанр.) Когда обнажается приём -- да, он может выглядеть скучным, надуманным, натянутым... Но в тексте, применённый с умом, он не только оживает, но и оживотворяет сам текст.

Comment: @Nektoid Извините, а можно мне этот стих увидеть?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец низзя. Он довольно слаб и воздействует только на эмоциональных женщин :)

Comment: @Nektoid  А может, я тоже из таких? :) Мы же не знаем здесь пол друг друга...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец то есть и Шарон, может быть, не... О, вы сломали мне психику...

Answer (score 1):

Ну какая может быть [дилемма](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0&all=x) при выборе из трёх вариантов?!

Тире хороши, не надо мучиться!

Запятые просто-таки расплодились бы - куда их столько подряд?

А скобки приберегают для других случаев, где действительно что-либо попутное вторгалось в ткань предложения, это более "сильный" знак;

останавливаемся на тире.